# C# / .NET 7 : Shopify Uninstall Webhook returns null response

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I am building a shopify app and the uninstall webhook is not working as intended

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> AppUninstalled([FromQuery] string shop)
{
    // ....
    // .... if user == null, log and returnOk... this is always null but should not be
}
```

This is my webhook in my controller, and in my other controller that creates the webhook

```
        await HttpContext.SignInAsyncUser(user);

        //Check if the AppUninstalled webhook already exists
        //Create the AppUninstalled webhook

        var service = new WebhookService(shop, accessToken);
        var topic = "app/uninstalled";
        var existingHooks = await service.ListAsync(new WebhookFilter
        {
            Topic = topic
        });

        if (!existingHooks.Items.Any())
        {
            // Create the AppUninstalled webhook
            await service.CreateAsync(new Webhook
            {
                Address = _appUrls.AppUninstalledWebhookUrl,
                Topic = topic
            });
        }
```

This was using shopify sharps documentation, im not sure why but shop is null and so is shopDomain which I should be from my get header request. I also used their example app with ngroc and their app ran into the same issue with my store, not sure if its a setup issue or if its an outdated way to go about it since shopify likes to switch it up every 5-6 months

My console shows that I get the webhook to fire with a POST /webhooks/appuninstalled but no 200 OK and the request is completely empty. I'm also very beginner so I probably explained it terribly but please let it slide :)

I did try changing the app version from latest version to shopifys oldest version available 2023-01 which didn't change anything.